# Jquery datatable serve side pagination

Tags: datatables

I am using  `jquery datatable`, I am doing server side pagination. I have implemented pagination on server which required `PageIndex` and `PageSize`. So I am calculating PageIndex and PageSize through following formula on server

```
int PageIndex = (iDisplayStart + iDisplayLength) / (iDisplayLength);
int PageSize = iDisplayLength;
```

It works greate , but problem is if I am on 3rd or 4th page and change `page size` and go to next page. Label shows wrong "showing xxxx records from yyyyyyy".
I figure out `iDisplayStart` is causing problem because it send the `start index`. what should be the right formula?

Answer (score 0):

change the "iDisplayLength" value in fron-end or where you are defining your table according to the page size that you are modifying. It worked for me.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
     ..
     ..
     "iDisplayLength": 50,
     ..
     ..
     ..
} );
```